# How can i get the result of a function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im not getting the result of a database query, instead im getting 'undefined'

Can someone pls tell me what im missing here?

DbManager.js

```
getCameras() {
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql('select * from cameras;', [],
            (_, result) => { return result.rows._array });
    });
}
```

App.Js

```
async componentDidMount() {
    dbManager.createDatabase();
    //dbManager.insertCamera('Canon Canonet QL 17');
    let data = await dbManager.getCameras();
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a `Promise` and `resolve` with the result.

```
getCameras() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql('select * from cameras;', [], (_, result) => { 
                resolve(result.rows._array) 
            });
        });
    })
}


async componentDidMount() {
    dbManager.createDatabase();
    //dbManager.insertCamera('Canon Canonet QL 17');
    let data = await dbManager.getCameras();
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a Lot! Works perfect!